# pycharm will not accept the presence of python in .venv directory in project

Tags: pycharm

I am using PyCharm 2023.1.4 on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

I cannot run my python script in the pycharm IDE because it will not accept the correct python environment.

I used "virtualenv .venv" to set up an environment. I know the environment works because I can use it on the command-line, outside of the IDE.

In the IDE, I see python executables in several other directories but not in this project directory. I can select one of those and then the .idea/workspace.xml contains:

```
  <option name="SDK_HOME" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/../../ca_ripa/.venv/bin/python" />
  <option name="SDK_NAME" value="Python 3.10 (ca_ripa)" />
  <option name="WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
```

What I actually want is:

```
  <option name="SDK_HOME" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/.venv/bin/python" />
  <option name="SDK_NAME" value="Python 3.10 (importing)" />
  <option name="WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
```

But when I change the xml directly, it is ignored.

As I said, in the IDE, I see many python executables.

Why do I also see this?

~/PycharmProjects/importing/.venv/bin/python

I, of course, have no "PycharmProjects" and I know that it is an artifact of the project creation. But why the heck can I not get rid of it? How is it poisoning my project so that it will not use the python in the project's .venv directory.